# Start animation without waiting delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this animation but not starting the slide 1 immediately, functionality starts after the 'auto_animate_delay': 8000, so after the load starts after waiting on the second slide animation or moving your mouse over the transition.

What is the path that I must follow so that the animation works well from the first slide and do not expect a delay

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var animation = {
                'auto_animate': true,
                'auto_animate_delay': 8000,
                'auto_animate_id': '',
                'caption_speed': 'fast',
                'panel_speed': 1000,
                'panel_easing': 'easeInOutCubic'
            }

            $(".item-list").css({"position":"absolute","top":"0","left":"0","float":"left","width": "100%"});

            var i = 1;
            $('li.item-slide').each(function(key, value) {
                $(value).attr('id', 'item-slide-'+i);
                i++;
            });

            $('.slide_caption').hide();
            $('#item-slide-1 > .slide_caption').show();
            $('#item-slide-1').addClass('active');
            //$('.item-slide').not('.active').children('.slide_image_slice').show();


        $('.item-slide')
            .bind('open', function(){
                if(! $(this).hasClass('open')){
                    $(this).next().trigger('open');
                    $(this).addClass('open');
                    $(this).animate({right: "-=769px"}, animation.panel_speed, animation.panel_easing, function(){display_slices();});
                }
                else{
                    $(this).prev().trigger('close');
                }
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                setTimeout(function(){hide_slices()},1);


                display_caption();
            })
            .bind('close', function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('open')){
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                    $(this).animate({right: "+=769px"}, animation.panel_speed, animation.panel_easing, function(){display_slices();});
                    $(this).prev().trigger('close');
                }
            });

        $('.item-slide')
            .hoverIntent(
            function() {
                animation.auto_animate = false;
                trigger_accordion($(this));
            },
            function() {
                animation.auto_animate = true; // auto en true para volver a activar
                clearInterval(animation.auto_animate_id);
                animation.auto_animate_id = setInterval(slideshow_animate, animation.auto_animate_delay);

            }
        )
            .click(function() {
                trigger_accordion($(this));
            });


        animation.auto_animate_id = setInterval(slideshow_animate, animation.auto_animate_delay);


function trigger_accordion(itemSlide) {
    if(!(itemSlide.is(':animated'))) {
        itemSlide.trigger('open');
    }
}

function display_caption() {
    $('.slide_caption').each(function() {
        if(!($(this).parent().hasClass('active'))) {
            $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('.item-slide.active > .slide_caption').fadeIn(animation.caption_speed);
            });
        }
    });
}

function hide_slices() {
    $('.slide_image_slice').each(function() {
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });
}

function display_slices() {
    $('.slide_image_slice').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('active') && !$(this).is(":visible")) {
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
}

function slideshow_animate() {
    if(!animation.auto_animate) return;

    var next_slide = $('.item-slide.active').next();
    if(!next_slide.length) {
        next_slide = $('#item-slide-1');
    }

    next_slide.click();

}

        });
```

Comment: Shot in the dark here but have you tried changing `'auto_animate_delay': 8000,` to `'auto_animate_delay': 0,`?

Comment: @j08691 following this: `animation.auto_animate_id = setInterval(slideshow_animate, animation.auto_animate_delay);` i'd say no

Comment: 'auto_animate_delay': 0, that option does not work because all the animation would stay without the interval, I need to remove only the first slide in the initial charge

Comment: By giving click the slideshow is active without waiting for the delay