# Insert multiple divs in list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list where need to insert the div for the list item, if use the simple .InsertBefore, will multiply infinitely elements

How can insert the div without duplicating other items?

Example: [jsfiddle.net/HJCps](http://jsfiddle.net/HJCps/)

Html Code

```
<div id="sorter">

    <div class="item item-1">
        <div class="text">Item 1</div>
        <div class="insert">Insert Text 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="item item-2">
        <div class="text">Item 2</div>
        <div class="insert">Insert Text 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="item item-3">
        <div class="text">Item 3</div>
        <div class="insert">Insert Text 3</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS Code

```
$('.insert').insertBefore('.text');
```

Comment: so what question you actually wanna to ask?

Comment: How I can insert the div without duplicating other items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HJCps/3/)

```
$('.item .text').each(function(){
    $(this).next('.insert').insertBefore(this);
});
```

References

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

[.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

`$('.item .text')` will find all the elements with class `text` contained in class `item`

`$('.item .text').each` will loop through every matched element one by one.

`$(this)` refers to the current element.

`$(this).next('.insert')` will find the next element with the class `insert`

`$(this).next('.insert').insertBefore(this);` will insertBefore current element the matched 
 next element with class `insert`

your code `$('.insert').insertBefore('.text');` will insertBefore all the elements with class `insert` to all elements with class `.text`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will use this option.

Comment: Maybe you could help me with another question a little more complicated [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747264/start-animation-without-waiting-delay)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might suffice (if I assume your main question right):

```
$('.insert').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().prepend($this);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HJCps/1/